# Helm require value without using it

Tags: mongodb, templates, kubernetes-helm

Is it possible to have a required `.Value` without using it in the template.

For example in my case I want to require to write a password for a subchart of mongodb but I won't use it on my templates so can I have something like bellow in a template:

```
{{- required 'You must set a mongodb password' .Values.mongodb.mongodbPassword | noPrint -}}
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ include "cloud.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    {{- include "cloud.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
    app.kubernetes.io/component: cloud
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.cloud.minReplicaCount }}
  selector:
....
```

And the result would be something like:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: blablablabla
...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Possibly the most direct way is to use sprig's [`fail`](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/flow_control.html) function.

```
{{- if not .Values.mongodb.mongodbPassword -}}
{{- fail "You must set a mongodb password" -}}
{{- end -}}
```

Assigning the `required` expression to a variable (that you never use) will probably also have the desired effect.

```
{{- $unused := required "You must set a mongodb password" .Values.mongodb.mongodbPassword -}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Let's consider the below `Values.yaml` file:

Values.yaml:

```
mongodb:
  mongodbPassword: "AbDEX***"
```

So, you want to generate the deployment file only if the password is set. You can do by using `if-block` of go-templating. If the length of the password field is greater than zero, the deployment yaml will be generated otherwise not.

```
{{- if  .Values.mongodb.mongodbPassword}}
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ include "cloud.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    {{- include "cloud.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
    app.kubernetes.io/component: cloud
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.cloud.minReplicaCount }}
  selector:
....
{{- end }}
```

**Reference:**

```
{{if pipeline}} T1 {{end}}
    If the value of the pipeline is empty, no output is generated;
    otherwise, T1 is executed. The empty values are false, 0, any nil pointer or
    interface value, and any array, slice, map, or string of length zero.
    Dot is unaffected.
```

Comment: Not exactly what I want, I'll try to explain it better. I want to evaluate a require (so the user must set the value when installing the helm) but I don't want to print it if they set a value. The rest of the template should be the same independent of the require. For example with `something{{ require "error".Value.pass }}foo` will result in `something12345678foo` if 12345678 is the value. I want to the result of it to be `somethingfoo`. With your way if the user doesn't set a value, the template will be empty and no error will be throw.

Answer (score 0):

just assign to an unused variable

```
{{- $ := .Values.foo | required "foo is required" }}
{{- $ := coalesce .Values.bar .Values.baz | required "bar or baz is required" }}
```